El label lblOtraImagen es nulo
soy estudiante de ingenieria de sistemas de segundo semestre. En POO se me pidió desarrollar un formulario con JavaFX que permita grabar, listar y mostrar los detalles de tres modelos:

TipoInstitucion; con nombre, imagen y codigo, el cual debe ser generado automaticamente.
Institucion; con nombre, imagen, tipoInstitucion (atributo de tipo TipoInstitucion), y codigo.
Estudiante; con nombre, imagen, institucion (atributo de tipo Institucion), y codigo.

Estos datos se almacenan en un archivo plano, y almacenan solo el codigo del atributo heredado. Ademas, la vista de los detalles de Institucion y Estudiante deben mostrar la imagen heredada.
Realicé el formulario y las vistas de crear y listar me funcionan perfectamente; sin embargo, el detalle de Institucion y Estudiante no abre y en la consola se imprime el siguiente error:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "lblOtraImagen" is null
at edu.poo.controlador.institucion.RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar(RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.java:66)
Este es el codigo:
package edu.poo.controlador.institucion;

import edu.poo.modelo.Institucion;
import edu.poo.persistencia.DaoInstitucion;
import edu.poo.recurso.dominio.Ruta;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles {

    private static Integer cambiarIndice(String opcion, Integer indice, int numEstudiantes){
    
        Integer nuevoIndice, limite;
        
        nuevoIndice=indice;
        limite=numEstudiantes-1;
        
        switch(opcion){
        
            case "anterior"->{
                if(indice.equals(0)){
                    nuevoIndice=limite;
                }else{
                    nuevoIndice=indice-1;
                }
            }
            
            case "siguiente"->{
                if(indice.equals(limite)){
                    nuevoIndice=0;
                }else{
                    nuevoIndice=indice+1;
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        return nuevoIndice;
    }
 
    public static Integer rotar(String sentido, Integer indice, Label lblNombre,
            Label lblTipo, Label lblImagen, Label lblOtraImagen, Label lblContador,
            ImageView imagenInst, ImageView imagenTipo, double anchoPanel, double altoPanel){
    
        DaoInstitucion miDao=new DaoInstitucion();
        List<Institucion> arregloInstituciones=miDao.selectFrom();
        
        int numInstituciones=arregloInstituciones.size();
        
        if(numInstituciones>0){
            
                indice=cambiarIndice(sentido, indice, numInstituciones);
                
                lblNombre.setText(arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getNomInstitucion());
                lblTipo.setText(arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getTipoInstitucion().getNomTipoInstitucion());
                lblImagen.setText(arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getNomImagenInstitucion());
                lblOtraImagen.setText(arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getImagenTipoInstitucion());
                lblContador.setText((indice+1)+"/"+numInstituciones);
                
            try {
                String rutaPersistencia=Ruta.RUTA_FOTOS_EXTERNAS+"\\";
                String rutaImagen=rutaPersistencia+arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getNomImagenOcultaInstitucion();
                String rutaOtraImagen=rutaPersistencia+arregloInstituciones.get(indice).getTipoInstitucion().getNomImagenOcultaTipoInstitucion();
                
                Path imgInst=Paths.get(rutaImagen);
                InputStream streamImagen = Files.newInputStream(imgInst);
                Image imgTemporal=new Image(streamImagen);
                
                Path imgTipo=Paths.get(rutaOtraImagen);
                InputStream streamOtraImagen=Files.newInputStream(imgTipo);
                Image otraTemporal=new Image(streamOtraImagen);
                
                double ajusteAncho=anchoPanel-(anchoPanel*0.4);
                double ajusteAlto=altoPanel-(altoPanel*0.5);
                
                imagenInst.setFitWidth(ajusteAncho);
                imagenInst.setFitHeight(ajusteAlto);
                imagenInst.setPreserveRatio(true);
                imagenInst.setImage(imgTemporal);
                
                imagenTipo.setFitWidth(ajusteAncho);
                imagenTipo.setFitHeight(ajusteAlto);
                imagenTipo.setPreserveRatio(true);
                imagenTipo.setImage(otraTemporal);
                
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }else{
            lblNombre.setText("Ho hay registros");
            lblTipo.setText("");
            lblImagen.setText("");
            lblOtraImagen.setText("");
            lblContador.setText("0/0");
            imagenInst.setImage(null);
            imagenTipo.setImage(null);
        }
        
        return indice;
    }
    
    public static int cantidadTotalInstituciones(){
        DaoInstitucion miDao=new DaoInstitucion();
        return miDao.numRows();
    }
    
    public static boolean eliminar(int indice){
        boolean correcto;
        DaoInstitucion miDao=new DaoInstitucion();
        
        correcto=miDao.deleteFrom(indice);
        return correcto;
    }
    
    public static boolean actualizar(int indice,Institucion objInstitucionEsterno,String ruta){
    
        boolean correcto;
        DaoInstitucion miDao=new DaoInstitucion();
        
        correcto=miDao.updateSet(indice, objInstitucionEsterno, ruta);
        
        return correcto;
    }
    
    
}

package edu.poo.vista.institucion;

import edu.poo.controlador.institucion.RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles;
import edu.poo.controlador.institucion.ControladorInstitucionVentana;
import edu.poo.recurso.dominio.Configuracion;
import edu.poo.recurso.dominio.Contenedor;
import edu.poo.recurso.dominio.Ruta;
import edu.poo.recurso.utilidad.Fondo;
import edu.poo.recurso.utilidad.Marco;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VistaInstitucionDetalle extends SubScene{
    
    private final VBox miVBox;
    private final BorderPane miBorderPane;
    
    private Label lblNombre;
    private Label lblTipo;
    private Label lblImagenInst;
    private Label lblImagenTipo;
    private ImageView imagenMostrarInst;
    private ImageView imagenMostrarTipo;
    private Label lblContador;
    
    private Integer indice;
    private final Stage escenarioActual;
    private Pane panelCuerpo;
    private final BorderPane panelPrincipal;

    public VistaInstitucionDetalle(BorderPane prin, Pane pane, double anchoPanel, double altoPanel, int ind) {
        
        super(new BorderPane(), anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        indice=ind;
        Background fondito=Fondo.asignar("fondoInstitucion.png", anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        
        miBorderPane=(BorderPane)this.getRoot();
        miBorderPane.setBackground(fondito);
        miVBox=new VBox();
        
        miBorderPane.setTranslateY(altoPanel);
        escenarioActual=null;
        panelPrincipal=prin;
        panelCuerpo=pane;
        
        crearObjetos(anchoPanel, altoPanel);
    }

    private void crearObjetos(double anchoPanel, double altoPanel) {
        
        String colorBordes="#b3d9ff";
        Stop[] arrColores=new Stop[]{
            new Stop(0, Color.web("#336699")),
            new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#6c99c6")),
            new Stop(1, Color.web("#97bfe8"))};
        
        double nuevoAncho=anchoPanel-(anchoPanel*0.4);
        double nuevoAlto=altoPanel-(altoPanel*0.1);
        Rectangle marco=Marco.crear(nuevoAncho, nuevoAlto, arrColores, colorBordes);
        miBorderPane.getChildren().add(marco);
        
        marco.setTranslateX((anchoPanel-nuevoAncho)/2);
        marco.setTranslateY((altoPanel-nuevoAlto)/2);
        
        construirPanelIzquierdo(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
        construirPanelDerecho(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
        construirPanelCentral(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
        
    }

    private void construirPanelIzquierdo(double anchoPanel, double altoPanel) {

        Button btnAnterior=new Button("<--");
        btnAnterior.setOnAction((t)->{
            indice=RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("anterior", indice,
                    lblNombre, lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
                    imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        });
        
        AnchorPane panelIzquierdo=new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btnAnterior, (altoPanel/2));
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btnAnterior, ((anchoPanel*0.15)/2));
        panelIzquierdo.setPrefWidth(anchoPanel*0.15);
        
        panelIzquierdo.getChildren().add(btnAnterior);
        miBorderPane.setLeft(panelIzquierdo);
    }

    private void construirPanelDerecho(double anchoPanel, double altoPanel) {

        Button btnSiguiente=new Button("-->");
        btnSiguiente.setOnAction((t)->{
            indice=RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("siguiente", indice,
                    lblNombre, lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
                    imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        });
        
        AnchorPane panelDerecho=new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btnSiguiente, (altoPanel/2));
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btnSiguiente, ((anchoPanel*0.15)/2));
        panelDerecho.setPrefWidth(anchoPanel*0.15);
        
        panelDerecho.getChildren().add(btnSiguiente);
        miBorderPane.setRight(panelDerecho);
    }

    private void construirPanelCentral(double anchoPanel, double altoPanel) {
        
        Font fuente;
        
        miVBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        miVBox.setSpacing(10);
        miVBox.setPadding(new Insets(altoPanel-(altoPanel*0.92), 0, 0, 0));
        
        //BtnEditar
        //**********************************************************************
        Button btnEditar=new Button();
        btnEditar.setPrefWidth(35);
        btnEditar.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        String iconoEditar=Ruta.RUTA_IMAGENES+Configuracion.ICONO_EDITAR;
        Image imgBorrar=new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(iconoEditar));
        btnEditar.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgBorrar));
        
        btnEditar.setOnAction((t)->{
           panelPrincipal.setCenter(null);
           panelCuerpo=ControladorInstitucionVentana.abrirEditar(panelPrincipal, panelCuerpo, Configuracion.ANCHO_APP, Contenedor.ALTO_CUERPO.getValor(), indice);
           panelPrincipal.setCenter(panelCuerpo);
        });
        
        HBox panelBtnEditar=new HBox(4);
        panelBtnEditar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        panelBtnEditar.getChildren().add(btnEditar);
        
        lblNombre=new Label();
        fuente=Font.font("verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 32);
        lblNombre.setFont(fuente);
        
        lblTipo=new Label();
        fuente=Font.font("verdana", 18);
        lblTipo.setFont(fuente);
        
        //Imagen institucion
        //**********************************************************************
        lblImagenInst=new Label();
        lblImagenInst.setTextFill(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));
        fuente=Font.font("verdana", 12);
        lblImagenInst.setFont(fuente);
        
        imagenMostrarInst=new ImageView();
        RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("primero", indice, lblNombre,
                lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
                imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        
        VBox panelImagenInst=new VBox(4);
        panelImagenInst.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        panelImagenInst.getChildren().addAll(imagenMostrarInst,lblImagenInst );
        //Imagen tipo
        //**********************************************************************
        lblImagenTipo=new Label();
        lblImagenTipo.setTextFill(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));
        fuente=Font.font("verdana", 12);
        lblImagenTipo.setFont(fuente);
        
        imagenMostrarTipo=new ImageView();
        RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("primero", indice, lblNombre, 
                lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
                imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);
        
        VBox panelImagenTipo=new VBox(4);
        panelImagenTipo.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        panelImagenTipo.getChildren().addAll(imagenMostrarTipo, lblImagenTipo);
        
        HBox panelImagenes=new HBox(220);
        panelImagenes.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        panelImagenes.getChildren().addAll(panelImagenInst, panelImagenTipo);
        
        lblContador=new Label();
        lblContador.setTextFill(Color.rgb(175, 20, 20));
        fuente=Font.font("verdana", 12);
        lblContador.setFont(fuente);
        
        miVBox.getChildren().addAll(panelBtnEditar,lblNombre,lblTipo,
                        panelImagenes,lblContador);
        miVBox.setPrefWidth(anchoPanel*0.7);
        miBorderPane.setCenter(miVBox);
    }

    public BorderPane getMiBorderPane() {
        return miBorderPane;
    }
    
}


En VistaInstitucionDetalle , veo inicializados los demás lbl, excepto lblOtraImagen, además, al ser un Label debería tener su propia clase y existir ahí o no ?

@Excorpion segun lo que entiendo, el lblOtraImagen lo estoy inicializando en el construitPanelCentral, en el imagen tipo

No, se inicializa en la clase, no dentro de una función. Si solamente controlas la variable dentro de la función, solo vivirá ahí.

@Excorpion entonces, lo que debo hacer es inicializarlo al crear en el constructor de la vistaDetalle?

Agregalo, y fijate en la respuesta que te escribí.

@Excorpion despues de agregarlo el problema persiste

Respondeme en la respuesta, pero, es el mismo error? por que si es asi, la imagen llega null. Fue lo último que te comente sobre los parametros.

En tu VistaInstitucionDetalle estás inicializando los Label
private Label lblNombre;
private Label lblTipo;
private Label lblImagenInst;
private Label lblImagenTipo;
private ImageView imagenMostrarInst;
private ImageView imagenMostrarTipo;
private Label lblContador;

Como podemos ver, el único NO inicializado, es el que nos dice el error. Entonces, lo agregamos.
private Label lblOtraImagen;

Luego, me mencionaste que dentro de la función construirPanelCentral, es donde los inicializaste, pero esto no es así, acá es donde los estás asignando. Como ejemplo tomaremos lblNombre.
lblNombre=new Label();
fuente=Font.font("verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 32);
lblNombre.setFont(fuente);

Y luego, es cuando llamas a la función rotar
RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("primero", indice, lblNombre,
            lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
            imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);

Pero en la función rotar, estamos llamando a los parámetros de manera diferente.
public static Integer rotar(String sentido, Integer indice, Label lblNombre,
        Label lblTipo, Label lblImagen, Label lblOtraImagen, Label lblContador,
        ImageView imagenInst, ImageView imagenTipo, double anchoPanel, double altoPanel){...}

Al parecer, y por lo que veo, lblOtraImagen es en este caso lblImagenTipo. Verifica eso por favor.

El problea está en este parte del código:
private void construirPanelCentral( double anchoPanel, double altoPanel ) {    
    ....
    ....
    //Imagen institucion
    //**********************************************************************
    lblImagenInst=new Label();
    lblImagenInst.setTextFill(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));
    fuente=Font.font("verdana", 12);
    lblImagenInst.setFont(fuente);        
    imagenMostrarInst=new ImageView();

    // acá llamas a **rotar()** pero **lblImagenTipo** se instancia más abajo
    RehacerControladorInstitucionDetalles.rotar("primero", indice, lblNombre,
            lblTipo, lblImagenInst, lblImagenTipo, lblContador,
            imagenMostrarInst, imagenMostrarTipo, anchoPanel, altoPanel);
    
    VBox panelImagenInst=new VBox(4);
    panelImagenInst.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    panelImagenInst.getChildren().addAll(imagenMostrarInst,lblImagenInst );
    //Imagen tipo
    //**********************************************************************

     // recien acá instancias **lblImagenTipo**.
    lblImagenTipo=new Label();
    lblImagenTipo.setTextFill(Color.rgb(110, 110, 110));
    fuente=Font.font("verdana", 12);
    lblImagenTipo.setFont(fuente);

Solo tenes que colocar estas últimas lineas antes de invocar a rotar()... suponiendo que construirPanelCentral() es llamado antes que construirPanelDerecho() y construirPanelIzquierdo(), si no así, tenes que quitar las lineas mencionadas de este método y agregarlas en el constructor VistaInstitucionDetalle().
Después de una revisión, me encontré con esto:
private void crearObjetos(double anchoPanel, double altoPanel) {        
    String colorBordes="#b3d9ff";
    Stop[] arrColores=new Stop[] {
        new Stop(0, Color.web("#336699")),
        new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#6c99c6")),
        new Stop(1, Color.web("#97bfe8")) 
    };        
    double nuevoAncho=anchoPanel-(anchoPanel*0.4);
    double nuevoAlto=altoPanel-(altoPanel*0.1);
    Rectangle marco=Marco.crear(nuevoAncho, nuevoAlto, arrColores, colorBordes);
    miBorderPane.getChildren().add(marco);        
    marco.setTranslateX((anchoPanel-nuevoAncho)/2);
    marco.setTranslateY((altoPanel-nuevoAlto)/2); 

      // el orden de las llamadas, produce la falla...       
    // construirPanelIzquierdo(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
    // construirPanelDerecho(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
    // construirPanelCentral(anchoPanel,altoPanel);    

      // modificamos para evitarlo o podemos trasladar la inicialización 
      // al constructor vomo comenté antes
    construirPanelCentral(anchoPanel,altoPanel);         
    construirPanelIzquierdo(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
    construirPanelDerecho(anchoPanel,altoPanel);
}

